# How to dynamically create json object with multiple keys and values using Swifty

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I want to create a json object using Swifty that I can parse to string in this format:

```
{
    "store": {
        "id": "test",
        "name": "store1",
        "type": "retail"
    }
}
```

I want to do it in stages in separate JSON objects (ultimately in separate functions) and then join the objects together.  When I try using the following code, I get an array:

```
func jsonTest()->String {
    var idJson = JSON(["id":"test"])
    var nameJson = JSON(["name":"store1"])
    var typeJson = JSON(["type":"retail"])
    var storeJson = JSON([idJson, nameJson, typeJson])
    return storeJson.rawString()!
}
```

result:

```
{
    "store": [
        {
            "id": "test"
        },
        {
            "name": "store1"
        },
        {
            "type": "retail"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting an array is because you are passing one in on this line:

```
var storeJson = JSON([idJson, nameJson, typeJson])
```

You are passing in an array with separate objects for the `id`, `name`, and `type`, so thats what you get out.

What you should be doing instead is creating a dictionary for the store, and setting all the values on that before passing it to the `JSON` function:

```
var store = [String: String]()
store["id"] = "test"
store["name"] = "store1"
store["type"] = "retail"
var storeJson = JSON(store)
```